# Delphi's RAD Studio\5.0\lib\debug Folder

Tags: delphi, ide, package

Perhaps a stupid question, but what exactly is the purpose of this Delphi folder?:
C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\lib\debug

..and why/when are *.dcu files put there rather than 
C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\lib\
?

I'm trying to find duplicate DCU and BPL files, based on an aswer I received to another question here, and it seems that the lib and lib\debug folders sometimes contain the same or similar *.DCU files.  Is this OK, or not... and when/why?

Thanks in advance for any and all help. : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DCUs and BPLs in the debug folder(s) were compiled with debug information so you can step into the functions provided by them using the debugger. If you check "Enable debug DCUs" (or something similar, don't remember) in the project options, the linker will use the DCUs and BPLs in the debug folder instead of the release ones.