# Debug dcu path

Tags: delphi, debugging

Please provide me some details about debug dcu path and where it is used.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667988

Answer (score 4):

Write the following line ...

```
procedure TFormMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('a');
end;
```

... and place a breakpoint (`F5`) at the `ShowMessage()` line.

After running the application, the debugger will stop at this line. Now press `F7`.

With the **Use debug .dcus** setting and a valid **Debug DCU path** (something like `$(BDS)\lib\Debug`, depends on your Delphi version) you will enter the `ShowMessage` procedure in `Dialog.pas`, without the setting you won't.

Comment: It also provides additional details to profilers (AQTime at least).

Answer (score 3):

'Debug DCU Path' is a Borland Delphi option found under `Tools > Debugger Options`.  It specifies the list of directories that, when the 'Debug DCUs' option is on, will be searched for debug versions of the Delphi Compiled Units used by your project.